# unable to enter n in the below code( cin>>n)

Tags: c++, error-handling

/**

Write a program that reads a series of numbers and stores them in a vector. After the user inputs all the numbers he or she wishes to, ask how many of the numbers the user wants to sum. For an answer N. print the sum of the first N elements of the vector. For example: "Please enter some numbers (press 'I' at prompt to stop ) : " 12 23 13 24 15 "Please enter how many of the numbers you wish to sum, starting from the first:" 3 "The sum of the first 3 numbers : 12, 23, and 13 is 48." Handle all inputs. For exam ple, make sure to give an error message if the user asks for a sum of more numbers than there are in the vector.

**/

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    try
    {

    vector<int> numbers;
    int num;

    cout<<"Now enter the numbers";

    while(cin>>num)
    numbers.push_back(num);

    int n,sum=0;
    cout << "Enter the nth number to find sum of elements till n : ";
    cin>>n;

    if(n >numbers.size())
    throw 66;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    sum+=numbers[i];

    cout << "sum is "<<sum;

    return 0;
}

catch(int k)
{
        cerr<<"Error "<<k;
        return -1;
}
}
```

So , when I enter EOF , CTRL+D , the program terminates. I am not sure where it is going wrong. I even tried to debug using gdb(with the help from an online tutorial) . It didn't just work out . can someone tell me what's wrong with the code ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking if you actually read anything.

[Consider this little test program](https://ideone.com/P3cC4s):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "std::cin is " << (std::cin ? "ready" : "done") << "\n";

    int n = -42;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << n << "\n";
    std::cout << "std::cin is " << (std::cin ? "ready" : "done") << "\n";

    n = -42;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << n << "\n";
    std::cout << "std::cin is " << (std::cin ? "ready" : "done") << "\n";
}
```

The output, when fed with an empty standard input (which is equivalent to immediately declaring its end with ctrl+d) is:

> std::cin is ready
>   -42
>   std::cin is done
>   -42
>   std::cin is done

As you can see, `n` is never changed, as there is never a new value to change it to! Also, you can easily spot that the state of `std::cin` reflects if the previous read went past the end.

Since you are only checking the value of your integers without ensuring that they have a sane default (just check what happens to `n` if it is not set by reading the input), this can easily lead to your program exhibiting unexpected behavior.

Note: The behavior of the test program [is different when fed input that simply is not a number](https://ideone.com/VkTRfG).

Answer (score 0):

When you supply cin with EOF it causes `cin.failbit` to become true. With the failbit set to true, all subsequent cin reads will be ignored. Since n has no default value execution becomes unpredictable from here. In my case the program was crashing because it was throwing 66. Adding `cin.clear()` after the while loop will fix this, but is not advisable. Two simple solutions would to stop on a magic number/prompt the user after every input if they want to continue.